# Утечка памяти в Adapter (Android)

Tags: android, recyclerview, утечка-памяти, outofmemoryerror, recyclerviewadapter

У меня есть `ViewPager` в котором 3 фрагмента.
Внутри каждого из фрагментов `RecycleView`

Во фрагменте делаю запрос на сервер, получаю данные и передаю в адаптер:

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SomeObj> call, Response<String> response) {

            HistoryAdapter adapter = new HistoryAdapter(context, someObj);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SomeObj> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Код Адаптера:

```
   public class HistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

SomeObj histories;  
    public HistoryAdapter(SomeObject histories, Context context){
        this.histories = histories;
        this.context   = context;

    }

//ТУт другие методы по заполнению ячейки итп.

        public static class ViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            LinearLayout player_preview;
            TextView  artist;
            TextView  track;
            ImageView cover;
            ImageView play_pause_button;
            TextView  time_history;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                player_preview    = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.player_preview);
                artist            = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_history);
                track             = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.track_history);
                play_pause_button = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.playPauseButton_history);
                time_history      = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_history);
                cover             = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cover_history);
            }
        }
    }
```

Вопрос в том, что после того как пользователь ходит по фрагментам или поворачивает экран Фрагменты удаляются из памяти. Но Адаптер продолжает висеть в памяти из-за static ViewHolder и приложение ловит OutOfMemory. Как решить такую проблему?

Comment: ViewHolder - внутренний статический класс, он не должен приводить к утечкам, по идее.

Comment: Выставьте у вашего viewPagera.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); И в манифесте у активити добавьте атрибут android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". Должно помочь

Comment: Как вы определили, что виноват именно ViewHolder? Как раз чтобы избежать утечек он у вас статический. Скорее проблема в другом.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать ссылку на контекст из адаптера.

Comment: `Но Адаптер продолжает висеть в памяти из-за static ViewHolder` – static в объявлении класса это не то же самое, что static у поля, поэтому нет, не из-за этого он продолжает висеть (если он вообще висит).

Answer (score 0):

Утечка должна быть из-за того, что ответ с сервера приходит уже в несуществующий фрагмент. Ссылка на фрагмент держиться и никогда не удаляется из памяти.
Проверить где именно утечка, Вы можете с помощью библиотеки:
https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Если все таки проблема в указанной выше ситуации, то есть несколько способов избежать этого:

1. Отменяйте запрос в onStop() методом объекта Сall cancel():
   https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#cancel--
2. Обрабатывайте запрос к сети в loaders:
   https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html
3. Уберите из Fragments всю логику, которая не относится к UI. Посмотрите в сторону архитектур MVP/MVVM/Clean Architecture